# How to define a template function, then in the template I can invoke it

Tags: php

From the [document](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/):

```
<?php

use WHMCS\ClientArea;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

define('CLIENTAREA', true);

require __DIR__ . '/init.php';

$ca = new ClientArea();

$ca->setPageTitle('Your Page Title Goes Here');

$ca->addToBreadCrumb('index.php', Lang::trans('globalsystemname'));
$ca->addToBreadCrumb('mypage.php', 'Your Custom Page Name');

$ca->initPage();

//$ca->requireLogin(); // Uncomment this line to require a login to access this page

// To assign variables to the template system use the following syntax.
// These can then be referenced using {$variablename} in the template.

//$ca->assign('variablename', $value);

// Check login status
if ($ca->isLoggedIn()) {

    $clientName = Capsule::table('tblclients')
        ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->pluck('firstname');
        // 'pluck' was renamed within WHMCS 7.0.  Replace it with 'value' instead.
        // ->where('id', '=', $ca->getUserID())->value('firstname');
    $ca->assign('clientname', $clientName);

} else {

    $ca->assign('clientname', 'Random User');
}

Menu::addContext();

Menu::primarySidebar('announcementList');
Menu::secondarySidebar('announcementList');

$ca->setTemplate('mypage');

$ca->output();
```

You see, the example gives the variable define, but did not give the function define.

I want to in the php file define a `function`, then in the template I can invoke it.

But I tried use `registerPlugin()` or whatever, all do not work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for achieving the target:

1. in your WHMCS system admin backend (System Settings -> General Settings -> Security), open the `Allow Smarty PHP tag`. then you can use

   ```
   {php}
       your_function();
   {/php}
   ```

   2.The recommend way is, allow for additional custom PHP logic in WHMCS templates, you could need to incorporate the use of hooks and define the variable before page load like

```

```
<?php
/**
 * Hook sample for defining additional template variables
 *
 * @param array $vars Existing defined template variables
 *
 * @return array
 */
function hook_template_variables_example($vars)
{
    $extraTemplateVariables = array();

    // set a fixed value
    $extraTemplateVariables['fixedValue'] = 'abc';

    // fetch clients data if available
    $clientsData = isset($vars['clientsdetails']) ? $vars['clientsdetails'] : null;

    // determine if client is logged in
    if (is_array($clientsData) && isset($clientsData['id'])) {
        $userId = $clientsData['id'];
        // perform calculation here
        $extraTemplateVariables['userSpecificValue'] = '123';
        $extraTemplateVariables['anotherUserOnlyValue'] = '456';
    }

    // return array of template variables to define
    return $extraTemplateVariables;
}

add_hook('ClientAreaPageViewTicket', 1, 'hook_template_variables_example');
```

```